# Find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ which satisfy the following differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ which satisfy

$3\dot x + \dot y +5x-y=2e^{-t}+4e^{-3t}$,

$\dot x + 4\dot y -2x+7y=-3e^{-t}+5e^{-3t}$,

subject to $x=y=0$ at $t=0$.

---

This is how I tried it:

If we multiply the first equation by $4$ and then substract the second we get the nicer

$\dot x + 2x=e^{-3t}+e^{-t}+y$

Similarly, if we multiply the second equation by $3$ and substract the first, we get

$\dot y + 2y=e^{-3t}-e^{-t}+x$.

If now we try to solve the first one in the usual 'particular solution+general solution' way and substitude in for $\dot y$ from the second, we end up with a new equation for $x$ but it still involves $\dot x$. So it seems like we are just going in circles.

Comment: if you added your two equations and defined $z(t)=x(t)+y(t)$ , you get $\dot{z} + z = 3 e^{-3t} $

Comment: I get $\dot z +z=2e^{-3t}$, but yes. Then I can express $x$ as $-e^{-3t}+e^{-t}-y$ and use this is the second equation above. If I solve it after this I get that $y=Ae^{-3t}$. But at $t=0$ $y=0$ so $A=0, y=0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: It looks like $y(t)=0$ and $x(t)=-e^{-3t}+e^{-t}$ does solve the system.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I thought I made a mistake. This must be the only solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

derivative of
$$y=x'+2x-e^{-3t}-e^{-t}$$
is

$$y'=x''+2x'+3e^{-3t}+e^{-t}$$

substitute in the second equation to get

$$x''+2x'+3e^{-3t}+e^{-t}+2(x'+2x-e^{-3t}-e^{-t})=e^{-3t}-e^{-t}+x$$
$$x''+4x'+3x=0$$
$$m^2+4m+3=0$$
$$m_1=-1$$
$$m_2=-3$$
so
$$x=C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{-3t}$$
$$x'=-C_1e^{-t}-3C_2e^{-3t}$$

so
$$y=-C_1e^{-t}-3C_2e^{-3t}+2(C_1e^{-t}+C_2e^{-3t})-e^{-3t}-e^{-t}$$
$$y=C_1e^{-t}-C_2e^{-3t}-e^{-3t}-e^{-t}$$

Comment: Great, thank you! I tried to express $y$ from the second equation and therefore it still contained $y''$, that is why it was not working...

Comment: Yes, and applying the boundary conditions we get the same answer as discussed in the comments.

Comment: @eeet1234 you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Put them in matrix form: let $X(t)=\left( \begin{array} {c} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{array}\right)$; then $\left( \begin{array} {cc} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 \end{array}\right) \dot X (t)+ \left( \begin{array} {cc} 5 & -1 \\ -2 & 7 \end{array}\right) X (t) = \left( \begin{array} {cc} 2 & 4 \\ -3 & 5 \end{array}\right) \left( \begin{array} {c} \mathbb{e}^{-t} \\ \mathbb{e}^{-3t} \end{array}\right)$.